# Mobile First 6.3 server - Faied to synchronize application runtime information. The servlet initialization failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

The deployment didn't have any issues for a month. Yesterday after deploying a new war and restarting the service, we got this issue. we tried to revert back to working war(backup) but still getting the same error.

Server upgraded from 6.2 to 6.3, Java 1.7

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0242E: Failed to synchronize application runtime information. The servlet initialization failed and the servlet will deny service due to a failure to communicate with the worklightadmin service. Common reasons are that the worklightadmin service is not started correctly or that the ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid property has not the same value for the worklightadmin service and the runtime.  [project xxxxxx]
>   Timeout while waiting for the management service to start up.120 secs.
>
> [ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout while waiting for the management service to start up.120 secs.
>       at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.isWaitingForSynchronization(AuthenticationFilter.java:602)
>       at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:139)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
>       at [internal classes]
>   Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout while waiting for the management service to start up.120 secs.
>       ... 5 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout while waiting for the management service to start up.120 secs.
>       at com.worklight.core.init.WorklightServletInitializer$1.run(WorklightServletInitializer.java:128)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: The application still works fine from worklight studio in local development.

Answer (score 0):

Undeploying the runtime, and reconfiguring the configuration, and redeploying the runtime again fixed the issue for me.